# Como criar campos dinamicamente ao selecionar um valor no checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Nesse script a baixo ele faz a contagem de *checkbox* marcados.

Como posso fazer com que ele além de contar, também adicione novos campos `<input type="text">` de acordo com a quantidade de *checkbox* marcados

Por Exemplo: Marquei 5 box, então mostrar 5 campos

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
   window.onload=function(){
     var contador = function() {
        var n = $( "input:enabled:checked" ).length;

        $("#checkcount").text( n + (n === 1 ? " é" : " são") + " selecionadoss" );
     };
     contador(); 
     $( "input[type=checkbox]" ).on( "click", contador );
   }//]]> 
</script>

<input type="checkbox" name="check1" checked disabled  value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="check1" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="check1" value="3">
<input type="checkbox" name="check1" value="4">
<input type="checkbox" name="check1" value="5">    
<div id="checkcount"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bem, isso pode ser feito de algumas maneiras, vai depender de o que exatamente você deseja com essas caixas de texto.

Escrevi um exemplo que leva em consideração a ordem dos elementos, ou seja, caso tenha marcado 5 checkboxes, terão 5 caixas de texto, se desmarcar o último box, a última caixa de texto sumirá, se desmarcar o segundo, a segunda sumirá... Veja se lhe serve.

### Javascript

```
var contador = function() {
var n = $("input:enabled:checked").length;
var unchecked = 0;
var cb = $(this).index();
$("input:enabled").each(function(i) {
    if ((i < cb) && !($(this).is(":checked"))) {
      ++unchecked;
    }
  })

  if($(this).is(":checked")){
    $('body').append('<input type="text" class="created">');
  }else{
    $('.created').eq($(this).index()-unchecked).remove();
  }

$("#checkcount").text(n + (n === 1 ? " é" : " são") + " selecionadoss");
};
contador();
$("input[type=checkbox]").on("click", contador);
```

Às `input text` criadas dinamicamente dei a `class="created"` para mais fácil manipulação.

A variável `unchecked` receberá a quantidade de checkboxes desmarcados posicionados antes do que foi clicado, esse valor será subtraído como o `index` do checkbox clicado, isso resultará na posição do elemento que será apagado ao desmarcar o checkbox. Sei que é algo confuso, mas é de fácil adaptação.

Por algum motivo o mesmo código que havia no JsFiddle e funciona perfeitamente, não funciona aqui, então deixei apenas o JsFiddle.

### [Exemplo - JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ryLod6cb/2/)

### Inputs criadas dentro de uma div específica

Para isso basta substituir o

```
$('body').append(...
```

Por

```
$('sua div').append(...
```

Utilizando o seletor de `id` ou `class` ou o que preferir. Segue um exemplo no JsFiddle

#### [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ryLod6cb/3/)

Espero que tenha ajudado...

Comment: Era isso mesmo Samir. só me tira uma duvida notei que os inputs estão aparecendo em qualquer fora de uma <div> . como posso jogar a saida dos inputs numa div

Comment: Bem simples... Ao invés de *$('body').append(* coloque a sua div desejada: *$('sua div').append(*. Era apenas isso?

Comment: Bem simples mesmo, show